# Wrong header footer view width size

Tags: ios, swift

Im creating a footer and a header view in code, in iPhone Plus, a glitch happens. The view width is smaller than it should be.
[image: PrintScreen]

I tried to change the local i create the view to ViewDidAppear, viewDidLoad and viewDidLayoutSubviews, but nothing changes.

The code for view creation is like:

```
let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 70))
```

It only happens in iPhone (6s, 7) Plus

Comment: How does the rest of the table view look? Is it only the header that has the wrong width?

Comment: Header and Footer has wrong width, the rest is fine

Comment: Did you try to implement the tableView functions: heightForHeaderInSection and viewForHeaderInSection? IF yes - could you please add your code?

Comment: theres no problem it height, the problem is with width. And the view is the table header not the section header

Answer (score -1):

Before adding headerView to its superView try

`headerView?.autoresizingMask = [
        .flexibleWidth,
        .flexibleHeight,
        .flexibleLeftMargin,
        .flexibleRightMargin
      ]`

Comment: Where is the headerView added, is it for tableViewHeader?

Comment: yep, its a tableViewHeader. tried to add in viewDidAppear, viewDidLoad and viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Once try to add headerview directly i.e by dragging view and dropping as header of table view in storyboard.